# Cannot load APK on device because non existing emulator appears and disappears in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After installing Android Studio 3.3, the "Select deployment target" toggles between no connected devices and a non-existing emulator.

Every time when trying to install the App on an emulator or a real device, it shows below error message:

```
02/01 18:05:26: Launching app
$ adb push /Users/jimclermonts/Documents/Android-Code/sources/app/build/outputs/apk/acceptance/debug/app-acceptance-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/nl.mycompanyname.acc
Device emulator-5556disconnected, monitoring stopped.
Error while Installing APK
```

Here is a video showing the strange toggling:

[image: in]

I tried killing it programmatically but it keeps booting itself:

```
Mac-van-Jim:~ jimclermonts$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5556   offline

Mac-van-Jim:~ jimclermonts$ adb devices
List of devices attached

Mac-van-Jim:~ jimclermonts$ adb devices
List of devices attached

Mac-van-Jim:~ jimclermonts$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5556   offline

Mac-van-Jim:~ jimclermonts$ adb devices
List of devices attached

Mac-van-Jim:~ jimclermonts$ adb -s emulator-5556 emu kill
Mac-van-Jim:~ jimclermonts$ adb -s emulator-5556 emu kill
Mac-van-Jim:~ jimclermonts$ adb -s emulator-5556 emu kill
Mac-van-Jim:~ jimclermonts$ adb devices
List of devices attached

Mac-van-Jim:~ jimclermonts$ adb devices
List of devices attached

Mac-van-Jim:~ jimclermonts$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5556   offline
```

it just keeps starting and stopping adb...

[image]

**Update:**

Deleted Android Studio 3.3,

Deleted these directories:

users/jimclermonts/library/Android
users/jimclermonts/.android
users/jimclermonts/.gradle
users/jimclermonts/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio3.3

Removed all Android emulators, Genymotion and .Genymobile directory as well.

Updated from High Sierra to Mojave, same problem.

Reverted back to AS 3.2.1 and added SDK. Same problem.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem... I tried everything I saw but nothing works.... If you find any solution you will save my week haha

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have struggled with this from yesterday on my Mac. Port 5556 is taken by an other app and that causes a fake emulator to be shown (in my case it was Videostream app)

Solution (in terminal):

1. `sudo lsof -i:5556` // or any other port that is shown as emulator name, you will get PID
2. `ps ax | grep [PID]` It gave me the file that used the port (it was one of the files in Videostream app)
3. I used AppCleaner app to uninstall Videostream (but simple removal is sufficient)
4. I killed the PID with: `kill -QUIT [PID]`

Comment: I had the same problem. Removing the Videostream App and then restarting solved the problem for me. No need for AppCleaner.

Comment: Thank you, this has been causing me so many headaches and your solution finally fixed it for me! Uninstalling Videostream was the fix!

Comment: Also experienced the same issue with Videostream, solved using this solution. Thank you!

Comment: This has been bugging me forever! I love Videostream so I will live the intermittent conflict but at least I know what it is now. Thanks.

Comment: After starting Videostream it will persistently listen on port 5557, causing this. But you can do `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.videostream.launcher.plist` to shut it down, and it will stop messing with your adb devices list yet still auto-launch next time you stop coding and stream a movie to your Chromecast ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried killing adb and restarting it?

```
 adb kill-server
 then
 adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below mentioned are the possible reasons and the solutions:**

- Close the current runing emulator.
- Disable instant run from ( Settings> Instant Run )
- Re-Open your emulator Again
- Check adb status ( adb devices )
- If still showing (emulator-555 offline )  try ( adb kill-server)
- Finally, Reconnect Server ( adb reconnect )

If still problem exists please check following guidelines

**Drivers not installed :** 
If the Android Physical device is not a google/Nexus product than you have to download the OEM drivers of the particular model.

**HAXM not installed properly :** 
Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager must have not installed properly on your computer. Try re-installing it directly from the options available in your SDK.

**No proper Path :** 
Sometimes though the files are available in the local system, The Android Studio is not guided with the accurate path name to reach the file.

Comment: I cannot close the current running emulator because there is no emulator running. I've deleted and reinstalled HAXM. No proper path? What do you mean? It used to work?